# PHP randomly dropping variables on MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running into a strange issue with PHP that has me a bit stumped. I am building up an insert query string from a loop (in the var `$user_query`), and then executing the following code:

```
    $user_query="INSERT IGNORE INTO user (id,user_name) VALUES ".$user_query; 
    $user_query=substr($user_query,0,-1);
    echo $user_query ."\n";
    mysql_query($user_query);
    if(mysql_error()) {$error=$user_query . mysql_error(); echo $error; exit;}
    unset($user_query);
```

then I run it:

```
    shell> php ingest.php 
    INSERT IGNORE INTO user (id,user_name) VALUES (24462186,'msbelindabee'),(478099020,'beenthat'),(294153799,'sh3lly05'),(22700530,'srcaino'),(755684,'hoony_ky'),(188148256,'judith_prietht'),(14687197,'realnicolezavala'),(467409503,'nicolezavalax3'),(35229813,'akaomar91091'),(560376223,'christophernineteen'),(1394834191,'punkpipes')
    INSERT IGNORE INTO user (id,user_name) VALUES
    INSERT IGNORE INTO user (id,user_name) VALUESYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 
    shell>
```

It seems that the `$user_query` var gets truncated sometime between when it is echoed and when the `mysql_query()` function is called. I've had this happen in a few other places in this script. I'm stumped - could it be a memory issue? I'm not getting any memory errors.

I have checked the apache and mysql error logs - nothing is logged.

Comment: try to replace unset($user_query); with $user_query = '';

Comment: unset shouldnt matter there much but it depends mostly on when and where the original value of $user_query is set. as it seems like a loop? When do you set the original value of $user_query? (thus the loopstructure would be an important piece of code there)

Comment: also you can echo all of your queries before executing them and see what kind of syntax error you have in your queries.

Comment: he did that.  The first is the "echo" of the first quesry, the 2nd line the echo of the 2nd query ($user_query is empty there when the insert statement is added) and the 3rd line is the output of the sql error (or do you mean $user_queryr when it is set the first time?)

Comment: he's querying the database in the next line. he should comment the mysql_query() and all of mysql functions just to see what's gonna print for him. once mysql_query() throws an error it will halt the execution.

Comment: its obviously an sql syntax error. Double check the syntax of your auto-generated queries...

Comment: not sure about the sql part there. as the output is: 1. iteration: after value there is something standing (the insert part), in the 2. iteration the string ends at the value part which then naturally raises the sql error. Thus in 2. and other iterations it seems like " $user_query="INSERT IGNORE INTO user (id,user_name) VALUES ".$user_query;"  user_query is empty when it comes to that line which normally should only be the case if he initializes the value that shall be put into the database outside (before) the loop but for that more code needs to be shown to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes perfect sense when this is happening in a loop. The first time you enter the loop the variable $user_query probably has the values you want to insert.
The query is echoed correctly and probably executed correctly (check this in your database).
Then you unset the $user_query variable.

In the next iteration you enter with nothing in that $user_query variable so

```
$user_query="INSERT IGNORE INTO user (id,user_name) VALUES ".$user_query;
```

doesn't append anything to that query.

Nothing happens between the echo and the execution, this code gets executed twice and produces an error on the second run.

Comment: That's the solution...this code *is* in a loop; on the first pass the query ran successfully (and quietly.) The second pass `$user_query` had no value and it echoed the query with no values. Then it echoed the `mysql_error()`. I had code in the loop to exit the script in the case there was no value for $user_query but it was not behaving the way I expected it to; once that was fixed it behaved as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Could be you need to increase the max_allowed_packet in MySQL

```
shell> mysql --max_allowed_packet=32M
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/packet-too-large.html

Comment: can the mysql max allowed packet size influence the echo there? (from what I saw in the posted output the echo triggers and the $user_value that is after the "VALUES" part seems empty.

Comment: No it can not. If the echo is incomplete, it should be a PHP only issue. Maybe PHPs error limit, but in this case the script should break completely and you won't see any output.

Comment: kk wasnt sure if I was mistaken or not (a good year since I last used PHP). yepp. looks more like the initial setting of user_query is happening outside the loop which would explain why it is filled in the first iteration but then empty when it comes to the add insert part.